# Multivariable chain rule - notation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Assume we have four functions $\in C^\infty$ from $\mathbb R^2 $ to $\mathbb R$, written as follows:
$$
x=x(u,v) , \quad u=u(r,s)
$$
$$
y=y(u,v) , \quad v=v(r,s)
$$
then, assuming the composition $x(u(r,s),v(r,s))$ is properly defined,
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}.
$$

But, in the particular case where $(r,s)=(x,y)$, we have that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} =1 $, but the right hand side gives us
$$
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$
which equals 2?

What am I getting wrong here?
Does my misunderstanding follows from a notation error?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: try writing an example where your stated conditions hold, and try to see which one of your conclusions is correct (and why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ doesn't equal $2$. This is one of those instances where regarding differential notation as cancellable fractions leads you astray.